# Iif statement. Output multiple columns

Tags: ms-access, report

So I've got another school related road-block:

> A representative from Northwind Traders will be in Germany. Management would like her to visit all German suppliers and customers while she is there. Provide a list of all suppliers and customers in Germany, including contacts and addresses. Designate on the report whether the company listed is a customer or a supplier.

Both the suppliers and customers use the same table values.  i.e. CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, etc.   Only thing is; I'm trying to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT IIF(c.Country = 'Germany', (Select c.Country, c.CompanyName From Customers c), (Select s.Country, s.City From Suppliers s))
```

Only instead of just two columns, I'd be outputting more than that.
And I've still got to make this into a report.

edit: Yes I have the where clause:  `Where c.Country = 'Germany' OR s.Country='Germany'`

Edit 2

```sql
Select IIF(c.Country='Germany',(c.CompanyName, c.ContactName c.Address, c.City, c.Country, c.PostalCode), (s.CompanyName, s.ContactName, s.Address, s.City, s.Country, s.PostalCode))
From (((Customers c left join Orders o
on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID) left join OrderDetails od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID) left Join Products p
on od.ProductID = p.ProductID) left join Suppliers s
on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
Where c.Country = 'Germany' OR s.Country='Germany'
```

Comment: The total lack of WHERE clause makes me think you're approaching this problem from a wrong angle.

Comment: I do have the where clause.  Just forgot to say that in the question.  Updated question to reflect such.

Comment: @Firestar001 I would recommend putting your entire SQL statement and formatting it as code.  To do this highlight your code and press the { } button.

Comment: I would create two separate queries, one for Suppliers and a second for Customers, both where country=Germany, and the [use a UNION](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e). I don't think IIF is the right approach.

Comment: @fvu Actually, yeah.  The union thing really worked out.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Select c.CompanyName, c.Address, c.City, c.Country, c.PostalCode
From Customers c
Where c.Country = 'Germany'
UNION
select s.CompanyName, s.Address, s.City, s.Country, s.PostalCode
From Suppliers s
Where s.Country = 'Germany'
```

There's the code that worked.

Comment: Yay! May I suggest you come back in a day or two and if there's nobody with a better answer **accept** your own answer as a signal for future visitors that this answer works?